# Is there a way to get all Gmail accounts with the recovery account?

Tags: gmail

I have a Gmail account with some other accounts that have the first account as the recovery account.

Is there any way to get the list of accounts from the main account? I have access to the main account, I just forgot some of the mails.

To make it simpler to understand:

Account B and C have registered account A as the recovery email.
Is there a way to get account B and C (the address is enough) using account A?

Answer (score 1):

Well I feel stupid for figuring it out so late, but once you register and add a recovery mail, an automated message with the address is sent to the recovery mail.